# Composite Key with Entity Framework 7 and SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite

Thank you in advance for your help!

So I'm working on a WPF application and using SQLite with Entity Framework 7.0.0-Beta8 as my ORM framework. I'm trying to create a composite key in order to  prevent multiple insertions of the same data. Unfortunately when I do something like this `modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceConfiguration>().HasKey(d => new {d.property1, d.property2})` with using EF Fluent code I get a System.NotSupportedException

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233067
>   Message=SQLite cannot support this migration operation.
>   Source=EntityFramework.Sqlite

The code that causes this error is here.

```
public class Device
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string DeviceType { get; set; }
   public UInt32 DeviceIdentifier { get; set; }
   public string PreferredConnection { get; set; }

   public List<DeviceConfiguration> DeviceConfiguration { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceConfiguration
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string DeviceType { get; set; }
   public UInt32 DeviceIdentifier { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string DateTime { get; set; }
   public string Configuration { get; set; }
   public string Reason { get; set; }

   public List<Device> Device { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; } 
   public DbSet<DeviceConfiguration> DeviceConfigurations { get; set; } 
   public DbSet<PidTuningSet> PidTuningSets { get; set; }

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
       string databaseFilePath =  "RUI.db";
       try
       {
           databaseFilePath = Path.Combine(
               Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
               databaseFilePath);
       }
       catch (InvalidOperationException) { }

       optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data source={databaseFilePath}");
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
           .Property(d => d.DeviceType)
           .IsRequired();
       modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
           .Property(d => d.DeviceIdentifier)
           .IsRequired();

       modelBuilder
           .Entity<DeviceConfiguration>()
           .HasKey(d => new {d.DeviceIdentifier, d.DeviceType});

       modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceConfiguration>()
           .Property(d => d.Description)
           .IsRequired();
       modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceConfiguration>()
           .Property(d => d.DateTime)
           .IsRequired();
       modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceConfiguration>()
           .Property(d => d.Configuration)
           .IsRequired();
       modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceConfiguration>()
           .Property(d => d.Reason)
           .IsRequired();

       modelBuilder.Entity<PidTuningSet>()
           .Property(d => d.Locked)
           .IsRequired();
       modelBuilder.Entity<PidTuningSet>()
           .Property(d => d.PIDValues)
           .IsRequired();
       modelBuilder.Entity<PidTuningSet>()
           .Property(d => d.Description)
           .IsRequired()
           .HasMaxLength(32);
   }
}
```

If I comment out the `modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceConfiguration>().HasKey(d => new {d.DeviceIdentifier, d.DeviceType});` code and create a new migration it works. But if I leave it uncommented, create a new migration and run it I get the above not supported exception. I'm not sure if this action is even supported yet in EF7 or if there is a better way to go about ensuring that there isn't any repeated data in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've create this key on the model level by just creating an attribute and using the [Key] tag and concatenating the values. I don't like this approach and I'd like to do this through EF if possible though.